# How many time I am able to upload my extension in Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, marketplace

I am upload my extension in **Magento Marketplace** but it is rejected more than 3 times for minor content error, I have question that Magento Marketplace give how many try to re upload my extension ?

Is there any limitation (No of try) to re-upload my extension ?

Comment: In which stage your extension rejected? In Business Review OR Technical and QA Review?

Comment: Any number of time i think until you are not get all issue corrected. Here all FAQ available you can check it. https://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/sellers/faq-sellers.html

Comment: @Divyarajsinh My extension is rejected in Marketing Review but this question is for all stages like Business,Technical and QA Review.

Comment: @AmanAlam Thanks for your reply but are you sure that we can re-upload extension N number of time after correction ?

Comment: Dude i already have extension on marketplace and faced these issue what i telling you is my experience with them.